# Android File not writing

Tags: java, android, file, filewriter

```
private void writeResults() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String TAG = Screen3.class.getName();
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "history.txt");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
        out.write(workout + " - " + averageSpeed + " - " + totalDistance
                + " - " + timerText + " - " + amountDonated + "\n ");
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

I have this code to write the stats of an user after a workout to a .txt file called history.txt but running this gives no errors. But when I browse on my phone to `Android/data/packagename/` there is no history.txt, how come?

Comment: When you say "gives no errors" - you're catching all exceptions and just dumping them to `System.out`. Are you sure you'd be able to see any errors that *did* occur?

Comment: My LogCat actually gives no errors for me, am I throwing the exception wrong maybe?

Comment: Well you're not *throwing* the exception at all... you're catching it. Again, this is being written to System.out or possibly System.err - are you sure that that output appears in LogCat? I suggest you test this by deliberately throwing an exception, and seeing whether it appears in your logs.

Comment: You're right on that one. I altered the code a little so that it now sends the Log to LogCat but this doesn't give an error neither.

Comment: @RoccoLangeweg Even in the new code you should instead use something like `Log.e(TAG, "Error", e)` to print the full stacktrace

Comment: Do you have the proper Android permissions for writing files?  Don't know off the top of my head which you need.

Comment: Use log or a debugger to check the result of `getFilesDir()`

Comment: The android documentation only said permission was needed for writing to external storage, so i have no permission for this now.

Comment: Check your file path again. If there is no exception when running you code definitely it will create that txt file

Answer (score 0):

you are not calling the external storage directory correctly

```
public class externalwriter{

private static File mFile = null;


public static String getFileName() {
    if (mFile.exists()) {
        return mFile.getAbsolutePath();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

/**
 * Creates the history file on the storage card.
 */
private static void createFile() {
    // Check if external storage is present.
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        // Create a folder History on storage card.
final File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +           
                      "/History");
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdir();
        }

        if (path.exists()) {
            // create a file HISTORYFILE.
            mFile = new File(path, "HISTORYFILE.txt");

            if (mFile.exists()) {
                mFile.delete();
            }

            try {
                mFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                mFile = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Write data to the history file.
 * @param  messages to be written to the history file.
 */
public static void writeHistory(final String log) {

    if ((mFile == null) || (!mFile.exists())) {
        createFile();
    }

    if (mFile != null && mFile.exists()) {
        try {

            final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter(mFile, true)));
            out.println(log);
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + mFile, e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Deletes the history file.
 * @return true if file deleted, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean deleteFile() {
    return mFile.delete();
}
}
```

follow this way to write data into a file which is to be stored on sdcard. tell me if this helps you